# How to get the Image Width & Height when doing Upload in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am making a **page in asp.net core** that is **uploading images** to server using **input type file** html control.

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="mediaUpload" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have also added the **[System.Drawing for .NET Core](https://github.com/CoreCompat/CoreCompat)** dll from **[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common)**.

Now on my post action I want to get the image Width & Height. This is the below code for it (but its now working).

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(IFormFile mediaUpload)
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(file.OpenReadStream); // error is here
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;
}
```

*The complile time error -*

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to
>   'Stream'  Goldentaurus    E:\Website\Goldentaurus\Goldentaurus\Controllers\MediaController.cs 453 Active

Please help??

**Note: My previous ASP.NET MVC 5 application(code shown below) was using a similar code that was working very well. I modified it to the above code to work on asp.net core.**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(HttpPostedFileBase mediaUpload)
{
    Image image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream);
    int width = image.Width;
    int height = image.Height;
}
```

Comment: `OpenReadStream` is a function, so you need to add `()` to invoke it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link https://andrewlock.net/using-imagesharp-to-resize-images-in-asp-net-core-a-comparison-with-corecompat-system-drawing/ it explains how to use CoreCompat.System.Drawing which is what you are supposed to use for .net core. It also compares it with ImageSharp. I used ImageSharp because I dont have to specify the operating system as is required in CoreCompat.System.Drawing, here is how I got it to work using the nuget package SixLabors.ImageSharp 1.0.0-beta0005 (make sure the Include prerelease is box in nugget is checked)

```
 private async Task<(int height, int width)> GetImageDimentions(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            List<string> AcceptableImageExtentions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp" };

            string fileExtention = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

            if (AcceptableImageExtentions.Contains(fileExtention))
            {
                using (System.IO.Stream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.IImageDecoder imageDecoder;

                    if (fileExtention == ".jpeg" || fileExtention == ".jpg")
                    {
                        imageDecoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegDecoder();
                    }
                    else if (fileExtention == ".png")
                    {
                        imageDecoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Png.PngDecoder();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageDecoder = new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Bmp.BmpDecoder();
                    }


                    if (stream.Position == stream.Length) //Check this because if your image is a .png, it might just throw an error
                    {
                        stream.Position = stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    }

                    SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32> imageSharp = imageDecoder.Decode<SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.Rgba32>(Configuration.Default, stream);

                    if (imageSharp != null)
                    {
                        return (imageSharp.Height, imageSharp.Width);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return (0, 0);
    }
```

You can also read https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/net-core-image-processing/
Hope it helps